# shopify how to delete page on app unistall?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

Hi I'm developing  a shopify app using PHP that creates a new page in storefront using

```
POST /admin/api/2021-01/pages.json
```

But I'm unsure how to delete the page when the app is uninstalled because the uninstall webhook gets fired after 48 hours and the access token is invalid.
Please help me out since I'm new to coding.

Comment: Once someone decides to delete the APP, you can't connect to a store that used the APP in past, if you really think about it is necessary, you create documentation on how to remove it or offer an uninstallation outside using a developer or collaborator account.

Comment: Will the app pass through  review if we just provide documentation?

Comment: Means no code is added to APP and submit to the review process?

Comment: yes
Will update the documentation

Comment: Nopes, you need to add code also for the review process as per knowledge.